# If you think I'm lanky now

Tags: word, story, letters

If you think I'm lanky now, I used to be even more sinewy.

> They took away a part of me.  Not wanting to lose more, I became an even bigger skinflint.
>
> Then they cut out my right eye—what am I now? The unkindest cut of all.
>
> I escaped, but found that while I'd once been swift, I'd lost a second. But I could still be an idol.
>
> Alone, I searched for answers; I only found myself endlessly. It's enough to burn anyone up (a little).
>
> Eventually I found something new, though the ferry ride cost me $1000. But what a wave!
>
> I left the terminal behind. What I did next was very wrong; in my pride, I cannot even speak of it.
>
> I'm afraid I lost my head. But at last I was no longer on the outside.
>
> But forget about all that is behind me. I am with you now, at the end.

**What was I at the start of my saga?

What significant changes did I endure?**

---

<sup>*Word set source: http://www.snopes.com/language/puzzlers/9letters.asp*</sup>

Comment: Sounds like a Pokémon's story...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You started out:

> **STRINGIER** - "lanky"

Your changes were:

> **STINGIER** - "took away a part of me" (-R), now "an even bigger skinflint"
>  **STINGER** - "cut out my right eye" (-I), now "unkindest cut"
>  **SINGER** - "lost a second" (-T), now "an idol"
>  **SINGE** - "endlessly" (-R), now can "burn ... a little"
>  **SINE** - "cost me $1000" (-G), now "a wave"
>  **SIN** - "left the terminal behind" (-E), now "did ... wrong"
>  **IN** - "lost my head" (-S), now "no longer ... outside"
>  **I** - "forget about all that is behind me" (-N), now "**I** am with you now, at the end"

Comment: Nice job!ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ

Comment: I dont get a single line of your solution :D (I am not a native english speaker, but... Still.. Not a single line make any sense :D )

Comment: Why does "cost me $1000" maps to removing "G"?

Comment: @justhalf - a G, derived from a Grand is (US?) slang for $1000.